# How to subtract a one interface from another in MRTG config

Tags: mrtg

I have setup MRTG for my router and I have create new target by adding all network interfaces together (lets call it Total_traffic).

I'm trying to create a new target which give total traffic expect one network interface. To do this can I subtract that particular interface from Total_traffic target?
I tried use `-` but didn't work.

Any advice helpful,
Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MRTG configuration does not allow you to define a Target as a function of another Target (the Routers2 frontend *does* allow you to display multiple Targets on one graph, or totalled, but not as more complex functions).

Instead, you need to define a new Target that makes the function you want.  Make sure to surround each token with spaces.

EG:

```
Target[foo]: 1:comm@rtr + 2:comm@rtr + 3:comm@rtr
Target[bar]: 2:comm@rtr + 3:comm@rtr
```

The MRTG manual is online [here](http://oss.oetiker.ch/mrtg/doc/mrtg-reference.en.html); you can see the definition of the more advanced Target syntax lower down.